# HighScore in Corona. File Read/Write

Tags: android, file, lua, coronasdk

I have this error:

> attempt to concatenate global 'Highscore' ( a `nil` value)

This is how I check for Highscore in Game.lua file :

```
function HighscoreUpdate()
    if(score>Highscore)then
        Highscore = score
    end
end
```

This is how I save Highscore in a score.txt  and I  call it after all the CollisionChecks ( i don't have any errors here):

```
    function savescore(hs)
        local path = system.pathForFile( "score.txt", system.DocumentsDirectory )

        local file = io.open ( path, "w" )

        local contents = tostring(hs)
        file:write( contents )

        file:close( ) 
    end
```

And this is how I try to load it (I think here is the problem):

```
    loadScores = function()
    local scores = {}
    local str = ""
    local n = 1

    local path = system.pathForFile( "score.txt", system.DocumentsDirectory )

    local file = io.open ( path, "r" ) 
    if file == nil then 
        return 0
    end


    local contents = file:read( "*a" )
    file:close() 

    for i = 1, string.len( contents ) do
        local char = string.char( string.byte( contents, i ) )

        if char ~= "|" then
            str = str..char
        else
            scores[n] = tonumber( str )
            n = n + 1
            str = ""
        end
    end

    return scores[1]
end
```

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any place where you are actually trying to concatenate anything with Highscore.  I also don't see where you are initializing it either.  By default uninitialized variables are nil.  If you are trying to print out Highscore somewhere like:

```
 print("Highscore: " .. Highscore)
```

you will get that error.  If you were to not have that error you would probably be getting another error trying to compare a number to nil.  So make sure you initialize Highscore somewhere and it should solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

USE THIS CODE IN YOUR MAIN.LUA

```
-- Read and Write Settings 
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
local path = system.pathForFile( "myGameSettings.json", system.DocumentsDirectory )
-- io.open opens a file at path. returns nil if no file found
local createNewMGS, errStr = io.open( path, "r" )

if createNewMGS then
   --do nothing 
else
   -- create file because it doesn't exist yet
   createNewMGS = io.open( path, "w" )
   if createNewMGS then
        print( "Created new myGameSettings" )
        local loadsave = require("loadsave")
        ----------------------------------
        myGameSettings = {}
        myGameSettings.HighScore = 0
        -- here you can create settings

        ---------------------------------
        loadsave.saveTable(myGameSettings, "myGameSettings.json")
   else
        print( "Create file failed!" )
   end
end
io.close( createNewMGS )

local loadsave = require("loadsave")
--------------------------------
myGameSettings = {}
myGameSettings.HighScore = 0
-- here you can create settings

-------------------------------
--read sittings
myGameSettings = loadsave.loadTable("myGameSettings.json")
```